# GraphQL stitch and union

Tags: express, graphql, api-design

I have a need to 'aggregate' multiple graphQl services (with same schema) into single read-only (query only) service exposing data from all services. For example:

```
---- domain 1 ----
    "posts": [
      {
        "title": "Domain 1 - First post",
        "description": "Content of the first post"
      },
      {
        "title": "Domain 1 - Second post",
        "description": "Content of the second post"
      }
    ]

---- domain 2 ----
    "posts": [
      {
        "title": "Domain 2 - First post",
        "description": "Content of the first post"
      },
      {
        "title": "Domain 2 - Second post",
        "description": "Content of the second post"
      }
    ]
```

I understand that 'stitching' is not meant for UC's like this but more to combine different micro-services into same API. In order to have same types (names) into single API, I implemented 'poor man namespaces' by on-the-fly' appending domain name to all data types. However, I'm able only to make a query with two different types like this:

```
query {
  domain_1_posts {
    title
    description
  }
  domain_2_posts {
    title
    description
  }
}
```

but, it results with data set consist out of two arrays:

```
{
  "data": {
    "domain_1_posts": [
      { ...},
    ],
    "domain_2_posts": [
      { ...},
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to hear your ideas what I can do to combine it into single dataset containing only `posts`?
One idea is to add own resolver that can call actual resolvers and combine results into single array (if that is supported at all).
Also, as a plan B, I could live with sending 'domain' param to query and then construct query toward first or second domain (but, to keep initial query 'domain-agnostic', e.g. without using domain namses in query itself?

Thanks in advance for all suggestions...

Comment: you can send domain name in header (using apollo link) like user token

Comment: Thx @xadm for suggestion, I will look into Link possibilities

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find solution for my use-case so, I'll leave it here in case that anyone bump into this thread...

As already mentioned, stitching should be used to compose single endpoint from multiple API segments (microservices). In case that you try to stitch schemas containing same types or queries, your request will be 'routed' to pre-selected instance (so, only one).

As @xadm suggested, key for 'merging' data from multiple schemas into singe data set is in using custom fetch logic for Link used for remote schema, as explained:

1) Define custom fetch function matching your business needs (simplified example):

```
const customFetch = async (uri, options) => {

    // do not merge introspection query results!!!
    // for introspection query always use predefined (first?) instance
    if( operationType === 'IntrospectionQuery'){
      return fetch(services[0].uri, options);
    }

    // array fecth calls to different endpoints
    const calls = [
        fetch(services[0].uri, options),
        fetch(services[1].uri, options),
        fetch(services[2].uri, options),
        ...
    ];

    // execute calls in parallel
    const data = await Promise.all(fetchCalls);

    // do whatever you need to merge data according to your needs
    const retData = customBusinessLogic();

    // return new response containing merged data
    return new fetch.Response(JSON.stringify(retData),{ "status" : 200 });

}
```

2) Define link using custom fetch function. If you are using identical schemas you don't need to create links to each instance, just one should be enough.

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink(services[0].uri, fetch: customFetch });
```

3) Use Link to create remote executable schema:

```
const schema =  await introspectSchema(httpLink );
return makeRemoteExecutableSchema({ 
    schema, 
    link: httpLink,
    context: ({ req }) => {
        // inject http request headers into context if you need them
        return {
            headers: {
                ...req.headers,
            }
        }
      }, 
})
```

4) If you want to forward http headers all the way to the fetch function, use apollo ContextLink:

```
   // link for forwarding headers through context
   const contextLink = setContext( (request, previousContext) => {
     if( previousContext.graphqlContext ){
         return {
            headers: {
                ...previousContext.graphqlContext.headers
            }
          }   
    }
  }).concat(http);
```

Just to mention, dependencies used for this one:

```
const { introspectSchema, makeRemoteExecutableSchema, ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { setContext } = require('apollo-link-context');
const { HttpLink } = require('apollo-link-http');
```

I hope that it will be helfull to someone...